# I want to find out how much zero come after 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

101000010 ,This number I want to find out how much Zero(0) come after 1.In Oracle kindly help me out.

Comment: [`SELECT 6 AS numberAfterOne;`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: After the first 1, the second 1, or the third 1?

Comment: You should give more examples along with the expected answers.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: yeah this isn't too clear if you just want to count total 0s it is easy just turn the number into string replace the 1 with nothing and then use length, otherwise @Derek is right what 0s are you trying to count?

Comment: Are you actually expecting to get 3 answers, one for each '1'? Should it stop counting once it's reached another '1'? Are you expecting 1, 4, 1 or 1, 5, 6? Please clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Your question will also be better recieved if you show an attempt at solving this and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I'll guess this:

```
select length('101000010') - length(replace('101000010', '10', '1')) "ZerosAfterOnes" from dual;
```

Result:

```
ZerosAfterOnes
--------------
             3
```

Comment: Or `SELECT regexp_count('10100110010','10') from dual`?

Comment: @Tim Lehner you made my day buddy it works thanks alot.